# MinIO S3 multipart upload with wrong ETag when file size is equal to the part size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio

I’m using [MinIO storage](https://min.io), but I’m having trouble understanding how the ETag is generated when the fileSize is equal to the partSize.

To illustrate, I created three empty files using the following commands:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=5242879 bs=1 count=5242879`
`dd if=/dev/zero of=5242880 bs=1 count=5242880`
`dd if=/dev/zero of=5242881 bs=1 count=5242881`

I manually set the partSize to 5242880 using the upload parameters.

When I upload these files to Minio via my application, here’s what I get:

| result | fileSize | expected | received |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✅ | 5242879 | 7c668eb59d6f0141a7863774100bfbcc | 7c668eb59d6f0141a7863774100bfbcc |
| ❌ | 5242880 | 81485c0e873d222199469076b60f30e9-1 | 1faefa44d632065e8bd4fd2a462ed292-2 |
| ✅ | 5242881 | 92f3a08aa3b1d7eb318ab9c2fc4a6ec3-2 | 92f3a08aa3b1d7eb318ab9c2fc4a6ec3-2 |

Can you help me understand what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an issue with the way your application is making the requests - I can't reproduce your results using the CLI.

---

Let's create a test file:

```bash
(test-user) ✗ dd if=/dev/zero of=1000-bytes-file bs=1 count=1000
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1000 bytes transferred in 0.002021 secs (494805 bytes/sec)

(test-user) ✗ md5 1000-bytes-file
MD5 (1000-bytes-file) = ede3d3b685b4e137ba4cb2521329a75e
```

---

Amazon S3:

```bash
(test-user) ✗ aws s3api create-multipart-upload --bucket test-bucket --key 1000-bytes-file --no-cli-pager
{
    "ServerSideEncryption": "AES256",
    "Bucket": "test-bucket",
    "Key": "1000-bytes-file",
    "UploadId": "xxxx"
}

(test-user) ✗ aws s3api upload-part --bucket test-bucket  --key 1000-bytes-file --part-number 1 --upload-id xxxx --body 1000-bytes-file --no-cli-pager
{
    "ServerSideEncryption": "AES256",
    "ETag": "\"ede3d3b685b4e137ba4cb2521329a75e\""
}

(test-user) ✗ cat multipartupload-struct.json
{
  "Parts": [
    {
      "ETag": "ede3d3b685b4e137ba4cb2521329a75e",
      "PartNumber": 1
    }
  ]
}

(test-user) ✗ aws s3api complete-multipart-upload --multipart-upload file://multipartupload-struct.json --bucket test-bucket --key 1000-bytes-file --upload-id xxxx --no-cli-pager
{
    "ServerSideEncryption": "AES256",
    "Location": "https://test-bucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/1000-bytes-file",
    "Bucket": "test-bucket",
    "Key": "1000-bytes-file",
    "ETag": "\"c019643e056d8d687086c1e125f66ad8-1\""
}


(test-user) ✗ echo 'ede3d3b685b4e137ba4cb2521329a75e' | xxd -r -p | md5
c019643e056d8d687086c1e125f66ad8
```

---

Same goes for MinIO, using the same file:

```bash
(test-user) ✗ md5 1000-bytes-file
MD5 (1000-bytes-file) = ede3d3b685b4e137ba4cb2521329a75e

(test-user) ✗ aws s3api --endpoint-url http://127.0.0.1:9000 create-multipart-upload --bucket test-bucket --key 1000-bytes-file --no-cli-pager
{
    "Bucket": "test-bucket",
    "Key": "1000-bytes-file",
    "UploadId": "xxxx"
}

(test-user) ✗ aws s3api --endpoint-url http://127.0.0.1:9000 upload-part --bucket test-bucket  --key 1000-bytes-file --part-number 1 --upload-id xxxx --body 1000-bytes-file --no-cli-pager
{
    "ETag": "\"ede3d3b685b4e137ba4cb2521329a75e\""
}

(test-user) ✗ cat multipartupload-struct.json
{
  "Parts": [
    {
      "ETag": "ede3d3b685b4e137ba4cb2521329a75e",
      "PartNumber": 1
    }
  ]
}

(test-user) ✗ aws s3api --endpoint-url http://127.0.0.1:9000 complete-multipart-upload --multipart-upload file://multipartupload-struct.json --bucket test-bucket --key 1000-bytes-file --upload-id xxxx --no-cli-pager
{
    "Location": "http://127.0.0.1:9000/test-bucket/1000-bytes-file",
    "Bucket": "test-bucket",
    "Key": "1000-bytes-file",
    "ETag": "\"c019643e056d8d687086c1e125f66ad8-1\""
}


(test-user) ✗ echo 'ede3d3b685b4e137ba4cb2521329a75e' | xxd -r -p | md5
c019643e056d8d687086c1e125f66ad8
```

---

In both cases, we get the expected ETag value for a 1-part multipart upload, based on the MD5 hash of the file.

Comment: I confirm that i can't reproduce with the aws-cli
It's apparently a problem with my application.
Thanks for the upload examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is a client side issue. The default part size in the case of mc is 16MiB

$ truncate -s 16M /tmp/16m

$ ~/mc cp /tmp/16m play/test/123
/tmp/16m:      16.00 MiB / 16.00 MiB ━━━━━━ 2.67 MiB/s 5s

$ ~/mc stat play/test/123
'Name      : 123
Date      : 2023-09-12 12:04:35 PDT
Size      : 16 MiB
ETag      : 3692065fc617ab1acea6dc7e886dc48a-1
Type      : file
Metadata  :
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

I also did the following using mc

$ truncate -s 5242880 /tmp/testobject

$ MC_UPLOAD_MULTIPART_SIZE=5242880 ~/mc cp /tmp/testobject play/test/
/tmp/testobject:    5.00 MiB / 5.00 MiB ━━━━━━━ 2.67 MiB/s 1s

$ ~/mc stat play/test/testobject
Name      : testobject
Date      : 2023-09-12 13:03:12 PDT
Size      : 5.0 MiB
ETag      : 81485c0e873d222199469076b60f30e9-1
Type      : file
Metadata  :
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Please check your client side code/tool and fix it

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I forgot to mention that I set a partSize manually. This is important in my use-case.
But I confirm that the uploaded file is not altered. When I download it and check the MD5, it match the source one.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the aws-cli, so you are right.
If it's not a problem of etag calculation, I'm reassured.